# Identities for $\operatorname E\left[f(X_1,X_2)\mid\mathcal F\right]$ when $X_1$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable or independent of $\mathcal F$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, independence

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space;
- $(E_1,\mathcal E_1)$ be a measurable space;
- $E_i$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $X_i$ be an $E_i$-valued random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ for $i=2,3$;
- $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal A$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$;
- $f:E_1\times E_2\to E_3$ be $(E_1\otimes\mathcal B(E_2),\mathcal B_3)$-measurable.

> Assuming $\operatorname E\left[\left\|f(X_1,X_2)\right\|_{E_3}\right]<\infty$ are we able to derive identities for $\operatorname E\left[f(X_1,X_2)\mid\mathcal F\right]$ when
>
> 1. $X_1$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable;
> 2. $X_1$ is independent of $\mathcal F$?

I've got an intuitive idea how these identities should be, but I don't know how to prove them. For 1., we should have $$\operatorname E\left[f(X_1,X_2)\mid\mathcal F\right]=f\left(X_1,\operatorname E\left[X_2\mid\mathcal F\right]\right)\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\tag1$$ and for 2., $$\operatorname E\left[f(X_1,X_2)\mid\mathcal F\right]=\left.\operatorname E\left[f(X_1,x_2)\right]\right|_{x_2\:=\:\operatorname E\left[X_2\mid\mathcal F\right]}\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\tag2.$$ Are we able to prove them?

Comment: The second one needs an assumption $X_2$ is $\mathcal F$ measurable. Indeed, taking $f(x,y)=xy$, $X$ such that $\mathbb P(X=1)=\mathbb P(X=-1)$ and $Y=X$ (with appriopriate $\sigma-$field $\mathcal F$) you'll get $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)|\mathcal F] = \mathbb E[X^2 | \mathcal F] = \mathbb E[X^2] = 1$, whereas $\mathbb E[f(X,y)]|_{y = \mathbb E[Y|\mathcal F]} = 0$. The first one looks pretty plausible

Comment: @DominikKutek Do you mean that we need the $\mathcal F$-measurability assumption for showing equation $(2)$ or do you mean we need this assumption to come up with an identity in the case of bullet point 2. at all? From your example, it looks like you've only ruled out $(2)$.

Comment: @DominikKutek BTW, if $X_2$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable, then $\operatorname E\left[X_2\mid\mathcal F\right]=X_2$.

Comment: Yes, at the end of my comment I said that first one looks pretty plausible, it maybe hold. I know that for $\mathcal G-$ measurable $Z$ we have $\mathbb E[Z|\mathcal G]=Z$ and it's main reason why for $X_1$ independent of $\mathcal F$, $X_2- \mathcal F$ measurable it holds that $\mathbb E[f(X_1,X_2)|\mathcal F] = \mathbb E[f(X_1,x_2)]_{x_2 = X_2}$

Comment: @DominikKutek Maybe I'm just a little bit confused about my own notation. Isn't $$f\left(X_1,\operatorname E\left[X_2\right]\right)=\left.\operatorname E\left[f(x_1,X_2)\right]\right|_{x_1\:=\:X_1}\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\tag3?$$ It should be. Then, if we assume that $X_1$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable and $X_2$ is independent of $\mathcal F$, it should hold $$\operatorname E\left[f(X_1,X_2)\mid\mathcal F\right]=f\left(X_1,\operatorname E\left[X_2\mid\mathcal F\right]\right)=f\left(X_1,\operatorname E\left[X_2\right]\right)\;\;\;\text{almost surely}.\tag4$$ Do you agree?